# Show a pdf on CakePhp after creating and seving it

Tags: pdf, cakephp

it's my first post so sorry in case i will do some mistakes. I am getting mad from this morning because of this function:

```
public function viewpdf0($agent_id = null, $month = null, $year = null){

    if(!empty($agent_id)){

        $this->create_remittance($agent_id, $month, $year);

        $this->layout = '/pdf/default';
        $this->render('/Pdf/remittance_0');
        sleep(1);

        $this->redirect('/files/remittances/STAT_'.str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.str_pad($year, 0, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$agent['Registry']['hash'].'_TEMP.pdf');

    }
}
```

The problem started when i decided to take off the calculations from the viewpdf0 function and putting it into the create_remittance function.

When i click on the button "Print Pdf" i get the following error:

Missind Controller for files. This mean that the Cakephp is processing the redirect thinking to find a controller called files!!!!

It's very strange, because if i put again the calculation functions directly inside the viewpdf0 function it works.

Below part of the create_remittance function:

public function create_remittance($agent_id = null, $month = null, $year = null) {
            $agent = $this->Registry->findById($agent_id);
            $this->set('agent', $agent);

```
        $conditions = array();

        array_push($conditions , array('Dossier.active' => '1'));

        array_push($conditions , array('Edossier.active' => '1'));

        array_push($conditions , array('OR' =>     
                            array(
                                array(
                                        'Dossier.item_parent_id' => '43'
                                    ),
                                array(        
                                        'Dossier.item_parent_id' => '44'
                                    )
                            )

                        ));

        //20:POLIZZA EMESSA - 17:PERFEZIONATA - 14:ATTESA DOC. ORIGINALI - 18:CARICATA              
        array_push($conditions , array('Dossier.state_id' => array(20,17,14,18)));

        array_push($conditions , array('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "Edossier"."date_emissione") =' => $month));

        array_push($conditions , array('EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Edossier"."date_emissione") =' => $year));

        array_push($conditions , array('Dossier.agent_id' => $agent_id));

        $query = array(
                        'fields' => array(  'DISTINCT Dossier.id',
                                            'Agent.surname'                                     
                                            ),

                        'joins' => array(                                         
                                        array('table' => 'items',
                                              'alias' => 'Item',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.item_id = Item.id'),
                                              ),

                                        array('table' => 'edossiers',
                                              'alias' => 'Edossier',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Edossier.dossier_id = Dossier.id'),
                                              ),

                                        array('table' => 'registries',
                                              'alias' => 'Registry',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.registry_id = Registry.id'),
                                              ),

                                        array('table' => 'registries',
                                              'alias' => 'Agency',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.insurance_agency_id = Agency.id'),
                                              ),

                                        array('table' => 'registries',
                                              'alias' => 'Company',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.insurance_company_id = Company.id'),
                                              ),

                                        array('table' => 'states',
                                              'alias' => 'State',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.state_id = State.id'),
                                            ),

                                        array('table' => 'categories',
                                              'alias' => 'Product',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.item_parent_id = Product.id'),
                                            ),

                                        array('table' => 'registries',
                                              'alias' => 'Agent',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.agent_id = Agent.id'),
                                            ),

                                        array('table' => 'states',
                                              'alias' => 'RenewedState',
                                              'type' => 'LEFT',
                                              'conditions' => array('Dossier.renewed_state_id = RenewedState.id'),
                                            ),                                  


                                        ),
                        'conditions' => $conditions,
                        'recursive' => -1         
                    ); 

        $dossiers = $this->Dossier->find('all', $query);

        $this->set('dossiers', $dossiers);

        $debug_dossier = '';
        $edossiers = array();
        $edossiers3 = array();
        $dossier_ids = array();
        $total_gross = 0;
        $total_taxes = 0;
        $total_equity = 0;
        $total_fees_gross = 0;
        $total_bill_tax = 0;

        foreach($dossiers as $dossier){

            // Query su type=1 ossia rata di pagamento
            $edossier_all = $this->Edossier->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Edossier.active' => '1',
                    'Edossier.dossier_id' => $dossier['Dossier']['id'],
                    'Edossier.type' => '1',
                    'Edossier.month' => $month,
                    'Edossier.year' => $year
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'Edossier.id ASC'
                )
            ));

            // Query su type=2 ossia storno di pagamento
            $edossier3_all = $this->Edossier->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Edossier.active' => '1',
                    'Edossier.dossier_id' => $dossier['Dossier']['id'],
                    'Edossier.type' => '2',
                    'Edossier.month' => $month,
                    'Edossier.year' => $year
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'Edossier.id ASC'
                )
            ));



            foreach($edossier_all as $edossier){
                if(!empty($edossier)){
                    $item = $this->Item->findById($edossier['Dossier']['item_id']);
                    $agent_name = $this->Registry->findById($edossier['Dossier']['agent_id']);
                    $state = $this->State->findById($edossier['Dossier']['state_id']);
                    $registry = $this->Registry->findById($edossier['Dossier']['registry_id']);
                    $cashflow = $this->Cashflow->findByHash($edossier['Edossier']['cashflow_hash']);
                    $edossier['Agent'] = $agent_name;
                    $edossier['Item'] = $item;
                    $edossier['State'] = $state;
                    $edossier['Registry'] = $registry;
                    $edossier['Cashflow'] = $cashflow;
                    array_push($edossiers, $edossier);
                    $total_gross = $total_gross + $edossier['Edossier']['gross'];
                    $total_taxes = $total_taxes + $edossier['Edossier']['taxes'];
                    $total_equity = $total_equity + $edossier['Edossier']['equity'];
                    $total_fees_gross = $total_fees_gross + $edossier['Edossier']['fees_gross'];
                    $total_bill_tax = $total_bill_tax + $edossier['Edossier']['bill_tax'];
                }
            }

            foreach($edossier3_all as $edossier3){
                if(!empty($edossier3)){

                    $total_gross = $total_gross - $edossier3['Edossier']['value'];
                    $total_taxes = $total_taxes - $edossier3['Edossier']['taxes'];
                    $total_equity = $total_equity - $edossier3['Edossier']['equity'];
                    $total_fees_gross = $total_fees_gross - $edossier3['Edossier']['fees_gross'];
                    $total_bill_tax = $total_bill_tax - $edossier3['Edossier']['bill_tax'];


                    array_push($edossiers3, $edossier3);
                }
            }               

            array_push($dossier_ids, $dossier['Dossier']['id']);
            $debug_dossier .= $dossier['Dossier']['id'] .',';
        }

        //Trovo tutte le rate pagate per conteggiare il totale pagato, nelle successive righe
        $edossiers2 = $this->Edossier->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Edossier.active' => '1',
                'Edossier.dossier_id' => $dossier_ids,
                'Edossier.payed' => '1',
                'Edossier.month' => $month,
                'Edossier.year' => $year
            )
        ));

        $edossier_ids = array();
        foreach($edossiers as $edossier){
            array_push($edossier_ids, $edossier['Edossier']['id']);
        }


        $total_payed = 0;
        foreach($edossiers2 as $edossier2){
            //$cashflow = $this->Cashflow->findByHash($edossier2['Edossier']['cashflow_hash']);
            //$total_payed = $total_payed + $cashflow['Cashflow']['qty'];

            $cashflows = $this->Cashflow->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Cashflow.edossier_id' => $edossier2['Edossier']['id'],
                    'Cashflow.active' => '1'
                    )
            ));

            foreach ($cashflows as $cashflow) {

                $total_payed = $total_payed + $cashflow['Cashflow']['qty'];
            }

        }

        $this->set('total_gross', $total_gross);
        $this->set('total_taxes', $total_taxes);
        $this->set('total_equity', $total_equity);
        $this->set('total_fees_gross', $total_fees_gross);
        $this->set('total_bill_tax', $total_bill_tax);

        $this->set('total_payed', $total_payed);
        $this->set('edossiers3', $edossiers3);
        $this->set('edossiers2', $edossiers2);
        $this->set('edossiers', $edossiers);
        $this->set('agent', $agent);
        $this->set('dossier_ids', $dossier_ids);
        $this->set('edossier_ids', $edossier_ids);
        $this->set('month', $month);
        $this->set('year', $year);
        $this->set('debug_dossier', $debug_dossier);
}
```

Comment: If you are getting `Missing Controller` error, you have an issue with your routing. I suggest you use proper routing. [See the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

Comment: you are defining `$agent` inside your `create_remittance` function but then you are using it outside the function when you call redirect. It's strange you are not getting an undefined error or similar

Comment: In case i write this: $this->redirect('http://crm0.convieneonline.it/files/remittances/STAT_'.str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.str_pad($year, 0, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$agent['Registry']['hash'].'_TEMP.pdf'); I get a strange url like http://crm0.convieneonline.it/http://crm0.convieneonline.it...

Comment: Looks like the CakePhp is processing the redirect looking at a controller called files, that off course doesn't exist.

Comment: `The method will return the response instance with appropriate headers set. You should return the response instance from your action to prevent view rendering and let the dispatcher handle actual redirection.` [Redirecting to Other Pages](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages). You aren't returning the response object.

Comment: Hi, i am looking and trying but without results. Can you please be more specific? What i have to return? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue just inserting an array return in the function create_remittance and in the function viewpdf0 i fixed in this way:

$remittance = $this->create_remittance($agent_id, $month, $year);

Thank you.